# The Messenger service has not been started - NetSend notifications will not be sent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-agent

In my SQL Server agent, I did not set any notifications, then why this error is coming?

I run pakg through `dtsexec` it executes successfully, and also I run a simple job for inserting record it runs successfully, but when in job step I select file system and give package path and run job it gives me that error:

> The Messenger service has not been started - NetSend notifications
>   will not be sent

I check in `services.msc` but there is no service like window messenger, I also check in `gpedit`, there is a window messenger, I apply its all three options enable,disabled, not configure one by one but did not get rid to that error.

any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

This is an informational message that appears and can be safely ignored if you are not using net send alerts.

If you wish to send net send alerts then you have to set the Messenger service to at least Manual startup, preferably Automatic. Then you have to start the service.

It does a check to see if the Messenger service is running, if it isn't then it produces this message as information to say "I cannot send net sends" but it doesn't necessarily mean there is a problem if you are not using net send alerting.

Answer (score 4):

Windows server 2008 have no messenger service at all. [msdn forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/b9c7c635-d6be-4cbb-a96f-fd1ccb9ccffd/) topic with additional info about your problem. Just ignore it.